# Custom page for dashboard, point me in the right direction

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am building a dashboard to track an item (SAMPLE) through its creation, logging, correction, and other activities. This dashboard doesn't have charts and graphs, but instead, I would like to have buttons along the side, and when a button is pressed the screen redraws to the new table (SPList). Other buttons I put in, just go to the page, and I want to avoid that.

The nice to have is the ability to put in a SAMPLE number and all information from all the tables would display.

Again, not looking for a solution, but if someone can point me to examples or instructions.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like either a job for PowerApps or a full blown SPFx solution. Are you familiar with any of those?

Comment: I think SPFx is for server only. PowerApps is one I keep thinking might be it, but would love to see examples besides what Microsoft has.

Comment: SPFx is a framework for building client-side SharePoint pages/web parts and works with both On-Prem & SP Online :)